# Problem compiling c++ project using Boost with Clang

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, clang

I've decided to try out Clang by compiling a c++ project of mine that already compiles under GCC. My project relies on Boost and as a result of including "boost/asio.hpp" clang issues the following error when compiling with the pedantic flag:

```
lib/boost_1_46_1/mac/boost/date_time/date_generators.hpp:37:30: error: extra ';' 
inside a class [-pedantic]
```

What are my options if I want to get this project to compile? I'd prefer not to have edit the various boost headers where this issue arises.

Comment: Any reason boost isn't installed in `/usr/local/` or similar?

Comment: None whatsoever. Although I'd be extremely surprised if doing so would resolve the issue ;)

Comment: I got errors in boost when using clang, but they went away when I put boost in a system include folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you giving clang the -pedantic option? It looks like -pedantic is triggering the error. You can always just remove that option.

Comment: Yes I am. Although removing the option would make the error go away I'd like to consider other solutions first. This would be a last resort...

Comment: I don't believe there is any other way. I just tried it on my machine. g++ doesn't report any error with pedantic. I don't have clang, but I'm guessing that it does recognize the semi-colon as useless. This is just a case where clang is more strict than gcc.

Comment: Eugh, as much as I didn't want to do this it appears to be the only way bar editing of the boost headers.

Answer (score 2):

I just looked inside the header and the problematic line is `year_based_generator() {};` which is a trivial constructor. So clang is correct and the `;` is unnecessary.

Since -pedantic is there to catch stuff like this, I think the best approach would be to inform the boost guys about this, especially since they aren't consistent about these semicolons so it's hardly part of their coding guidelines.

Instead of disabling -pedantic on a whole you could use pragmas to disable it only for the problematic boost libraries.

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-pedantic"
// include boost headers
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Should work I think.

Comment: I actually went down this route at one point, it results in a new error, the gist of which reads: pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-pedantic".

Comment: That's strange - according to (this here)[http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#diagnostics_commandline] that's valid code. Can't test it atm (no clang here) but I'm surprised this doesn't work.

Comment: Sadly -Wpedantic does not work either and results in: "error: unknown warning group '-Wpedantic', ignored [-Wunknown-pragmas]"